# How do I quicksave when using a controller?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

There is a keyboard shortcut to quicksave (<kbd>F5</kbd>), but since I switched to playing with an Xbox controller I can't find any option to quicksave anymore.

Is the option to quicksave hidden somewhere, or is there actually no way to quicksave when using the controller?

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know there isn't a way to quicksave with a controller, on console the manual quicksave is disabled. The only way i can think about is to use a 3rd party tool like xpadder and bind a specific button to f5.